# Example of IOSurfaceCreateMachPort and IOSurfaceLookupFromMachPort?

Tags: macos

Can anyone point me to a code example that uses IOSurfaceCreateMachPort and IOSurfaceLookupFromMachPort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fdiv.net/2011/01/27/example-iosurfacecreatemachport-and-iosurfacelookupfrommachport